# Compile whole node.js project with closure compiler

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-closure-compiler

I am trying to use closure compiler to perform static type checking for my project, but I cannot get the compiler to recursively go through all the files required. When I do

```
ccjs app.js
```

it will only compile app.js, instead of trying to resolve all the files required and check if there is any type error with calling the functions in the required module. How can I compile my whole node.js project with closure compiler for static type checking? If not, is there any alternatives to do that?